# Unable to render ant design icons within the option label of Select component

Tags: reactjs, icons, antd

Ant Design's label property of the option does require only string values to be placed within it. I need to have an icon with the text in the options of Select. When I try to use what I see is
`[object Object] text`
Whereas the `[object Object]` should have been the ant design icon.

```js
<Select
  mode="multiple"
  placeholder="Please select"
  // defaultValue={['a10', 'c12']}
  suffixIcon={<UserOutlined />}
  style={{
    width: '100%',
  }}
  options={[{ value: 'text1', label: <UserOutlined /> + 'text1' }, { value: 'text2', label: 'text2'}]}
/>
```

I could use

```
<Option value='text1'> <UserOutlined /> Text </Option>
<Option value='text2'> <UserOutlined /> Text </Option>
<Option value='text3'> <UserOutlined /> Text </Option>
```

which actually gives what I want. But the option list I have is dynamic and huge.

Is there a standard yet easy way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add up a string and an object. A possible solution is to wrap the `UserOutlined` component and your `text` in a **fragment**.

```js
<Select
  mode="multiple"
  placeholder="Please select"
  // defaultValue={['a10', 'c12']}
  suffixIcon={<UserOutlined />}
  style={{
    width: "100%",
  }}
  options={[
    {
      value: "text1",
      label: (
        <>
          <UserOutlined />{" "}text1
        </>
      ),
    },
    { value: "text2", label: "text2" },
  ]}
/>
```